# In Javascript, is there an equivalent of a "find if", or a compact way of doing what I'm trying to do?

Tags: javascript, c++, algorithm

I have an ugly piece of Javascript code

```
for (var k = 0; k < ogmap.length; ++k)
{
    if (ogmap[k]["orgname"] == curSelectedOrg)
    {
        ogmap[k]["catnames"].push(newCatName);
        break;
    }
}
```

Actually, I have a lot of pieces like that in my web app.

I'm wondering if there's a way to make it prettier and compacter. I know there are nice ways of doing this in other languages, like using `find_if` in C++ (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/find_if/) or `FirstOrDefault` in C# or fancy LINQ queries in C#.

At the very least, help me make that slightly more readable.

Comment: How about something like this? http://underscorejs.org/#findIndex

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say that you can just write yourself a utility function and then use it whenever necessary.

```
// finds the first object in the array that has the desired property
// with a value that matches the passed in val
// returns the index in the array of the match
// or returns -1 if no match found
function findPropMatch(array, propName, val) {
   var item;
   for (var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       item = array[i];
       if (typeof item === "object" && item[propName] === val) {
           return i;
       }
   }
   return -1;
}
```

And, then you can use it like this:

```
var match = findPropMatch(ogmap, "orgname", curSelectedOrg);
if (match !== -1) {
    ogmap[match]["catnames"].push(newCatName);
}
```

Comment: Why the downvote?  Does this not do exactly what the OP asked for?  Downvotes without any explanation provide no feedback for how to improve the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
var find_if = function (arr, pred) {
    var i = -1;
    arr.some(function (item, ind) {
        if (pred(item)) {
            i = ind;
            return true;
        }
    });
    return i;
}
```

Call it like

```
var item_or_last = find_if(_.range(ogmap.length), function (item) {
    return item["orgname"] == curSelectedOrg
});
```

Or without underscore.js

```
var range = function (a, b) {
    var low = a < b ? a : b;
    var high = a > b ? a : b;
    var ret = [];
    while (low < high) {
        ret.push(low++);
    }
    return ret;  
}
var item_or_last = find_if(range(0, ogmap.length), function (item) {
    return item["orgname"] == curSelectedOrg
});
```

This lets you declare what you are looking for instead of looping over items and checking each one.

Comment: Why is this answer using the underscore library?  Did the OP ask for that?

Comment: @jfriend just an easy way to turn two numbers into an array of incrementing numbers

Comment: @jfriend00 Added another solution that removes underscore dependency.

Comment: Something doesn't look right here.  You're returning the desired item from the `.forEach()`callback  but that doesn't return from the outer function or even stop the `.forEach()` looping.

Comment: @jfriend00 yeah thanks for catching that. I've been messing with it to look better. I'll go back to my original answer.

Comment: In general `.forEach()` is just the wrong choice when you want to stop the iteration as soon as you find a match.

Comment: @jfriend00 how about this. array.some() short circuits when it something returns true

Comment: Yes, `.some()` is a better choice that `.forEach()`.  The manual `for` loop iteration in my answer allows you to directly return from the outer function which avoids an intermediate variable and I think just makes more readable code for this type of problem.  But `.some()` will work.